# Syntax Error when directly access attribute on empty object {}

Tags: javascript, syntax, syntax-error

```
> "[object Number]" === Object.prototype.toString.call(1) // #1
< true
> "[object Number]" === {}.toString.call(1)               // #2
< true
> {}.toString.call(1) === "[object Number]"               // #3
< SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'
> ({}).toString.call(1) === "[object Number]"             // #4
< true
> {}.toString.call(1)                                     // #5
< SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'
> !{}.toString.call(1)                                    // #6
< false
> test = {}.toString.call(1)                              // #7
< "[object Number]"
```

As you can see from the sample, #2 and #3 are almost identical except that the they have the left and right side exchanged. #2 works fine but #3 gives a syntax error. To get #3 to work, a pair of parentheses is required. Additionally, from #5-7 we can see that as long as `{}` is not at the left most, it works fine.

But why?

Comment: I guess `{}` is an object literal and is not assigned to any variable, hence it is not initialised to object yet. Considering the possibility of `{....}` scope

Comment: `{}` is a block in that case.

Comment: @Xufox: Why it is a block? If you type '{}' in console, it returns '{}' - an object. Also, this is tested on desktop browser, not in node.

Comment: It's not a block, cuz `{ var q = 1 }` throws an error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`

Comment: @edward That’s the case in Chrome, not in Firefox. Chrome implicitly wraps everything in `(`…`)`. There even used to be a version where `{}) + ({}` was valid in the console (not sure if it’s still there). In JS, `{}` is still a block.

Comment: @Xufox It seems to make sense. However, in further tests, blocks do not work as the beginning of a statement as well. `var x = 1; {var x = 2;}` works fine, but `{var x = 1;}` gives syntax error. This seems to indicate that it is not a block?

Comment: As mentioned in the answer, when {} found at beginning, javascript thinks that is a curly brace if there is no operator or expression associated with it

Answer (score 1):

In #1, when it finds `rvalue` and an operator `===`, javascript considers that the `lvalue` could be a value or an expression.

In #2, same as #1. hence `{}` is considered as an object literal

In #3, since javascript evaluates the statement from right to left, the `{}` is considered just as a curly brace but not an object literal. hence #3 is not working because you won't be getting `toString` function on curly braces.

In #4, when you enclose `{}` within `()` grouping operator, javascript thinks it is an expression. hence #4 works because `{}` is evaluated as an object literal and `toString` be available.

In #5, same as #3. javascript thinks that `{}` as just a brace since there is not expressions or with it.

In #6, same as #4. there is an expression `!` . hence is evaluated as an object

In #7, same as #4. there is an assignment operator, hence is evaluated as an expression.

Comment: It is indeed a block per Mozilla doc: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#Object_literals